# Cannot read Properties of undefined (reading 'location') in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const useQuery = () => new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
export const useQueryWithSearch = (search) => new URLSearchParams(search);

export default useQuery;
```

I have installed react-router-dom @5.2.0

Comment: Did you wrap you App with BrowserRouter?

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:next.js], so assuming you're using Next.js you should be using its built-in router, not `react-router-dom`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router.